# high performance data structure for large amounts of data

Tags: c#, performance, data-structures, word-processor

I am working on the .NET version of a "word processor" control for large documents - large meaning up to 10000 pages when printed.

I have implemented the functionality with Win32 a few years ago using arrays to hold line pointers, growing the arrays in blocks as needed and calling RtlMoveMemory (kernel32.dll) to shift the pointers.

The main performance issues are

- Document is loaded in order from line 1 to last...
- mouse move needs to find a line by its "pixel" offset from the top of the document to adjust the mouse cursor.
- Painting needs to find a line by its offset and iterate through the next lines
- Insertion and deletion must not take ages (word wrapping)

I have read a lot about

- SortedList: super fast for loading, but what about insertion?
- SplayTree: sounds good because user moves mouse over the same lines a lot, but what about scrolling from bottom to mid of document?
- SkipList: sounds like a good overall performer, but has memory issues with high data volume?
- SortedDictionary and AVL tree: disqualified for slow in order loading.
- RedBlack Tree: nowhere best, but nowhere worst? Is this the best choice?

Are those structures capable of good performance with a million entries?
If so, what would be the best choice?

I may have missed other ideas/classes.

I want to stick to managed code if possible, but am ready switch to dirty code if needed.

Comment: Is it so hard to try the different possibilities you list?

Comment: Yes. This will be my first use of .NET ever. But you seem so experienced that I would have expected a constructive answer. Thanks

Comment: If you're looking for what sorts of data structures are used for text processing, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169440/text-editor-theory/3169491